# How to position BottomSheetScaffold' sheetContent right below another view

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My BottomSheetScaffold content has a composable on the screen top below the appbar, when I click at an item in the screen I would like a bottom sheet to appear and use all the space available until the mentioned header in the BottomSheetScaffold' content. The youtube app for example does this when you press on the comments section. Any idea how they achieved this?